# Response.redirect in vbscript

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, vbscript

Can you tell me a vbscript for doing an action just like response.redirect command

doing in asp.net.I need to got to one page from another page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Response.Redirect. Regardless if you are using ASP or ASP.NET, it's available.

Answer (score 4):

```
Response.CodePage = 1252  
Response.Redirect ("http://www.microsoft.com" )
```

Comment: i need it in vbscript not in javascript

Comment: Parentheses not required in this case and can lead to problems.

Comment: previously there was window.location and now he changed,,any way thats my mistake window.location will work in vbscript

Comment: whats here Response.CodePage = 1252,,what is 1252 here

Comment: @Peter: window.location is a client side browser thing.  You question relates to server side right.  1252 refers to the Windows-1252 characters set, Response.CodePage controls how string passed to Response.Write are encoded before being placed in the output buffer.  I'm not sure there is any point assigning when doing a redirection.

Comment: You can't declare and assign a variable on the same line in ASP classic

Comment: @jammus : you're right, I fixed it now... although that's not really the point of this answer, and thus I don't really see the reason for the downvote

Comment: Because yours was the top answer and was incorrect. Also, the codepage line isn't really required. You're right though, I should have given you time to edit your answer before downvoting you.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try Response.Redirect in VBScript?

Much of the Response, Request, Server, Session and Application interface of ASP.NET was drawn from the originals in ASP classic.